# How to use rscada python-mbus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, protocols, iot

Does anyone knows how to use [rscada python-mbus](https://github.com/rscada/python-mbus)?

The example does not work on my computer, it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "C:\Users\Tiago\Desktop\MbusSerial.py", line 10, in <module>
      mbus = MBus.MBus()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\mbus\MBus.py", line 66, in __init__
      self._libmbus = MBusLib(libpath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\mbus\MBusLowLevel.py", line 191, in __init__
      lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
      return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
      self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) 
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
Exception ignored in: <bound method MBus.__del__ of <mbus.MBus.MBus object at 0x0000026E6836A8D0>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\mbus\MBus.py", line 97, in __del__
      if self.handle: 
AttributeError: 'MBus' object has no attribute 'handle'
```

In my scenario i have [image: this]

Sorry about my drawing skills, M-Bus and Laptop are connected by serial

Any help?
I'm also available to look at other solutions to read M-bus data from the serial port and make it humanlly readable.